# Plug-in for one-time login

Tags: php, joomla1.5

I am doing an intranet site for my company by using Joomla.  I need a plugin or component for a one time login (its not a single sign-on concept).

The user only needs to give the username and password for the machine or PC, then it will not ask the user to login to the Joomla site again; instead, it should take the user to site.

My aim is that the user needs not to give the username and password again for the Joomla site.  Is this possible?  Is there any plugin or component like this in Joomla?

Comment: @Ryan Kohn -- please don't suggest edits like this.  You simply removed the salutation, and didn't bother to clean up the rest of the question.  This edit really should have been rejected as "too minor".  See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116656/too-minor-edit-reason-can-sometimes-be-a-little-contradictory, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122923/why-can-suggested-edits-be-too-minor and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110153/approve-suggested-edits-when-only-the-signature-is-removed.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables I appreciate the feedback; it's much appreciated!